# Can users access data you don't want on firebase?

Tags: python, firebase

I want to make an app that stores user data using firestore from firebase. My question is: Is there any possible way for a hacker to somehow access the database? I still want to be able to read/write/delete/edit from inside the app.(I'm using Python)

Comment: There are [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) which can be used to restrict access to your data. Can you clarify your use case so it'll be easier to explain what kind of rules you are looking for ?

Comment: I want to store passwords, emails, usernames, descriptions, profile picture and some kind of friend list. I wonder if the app can edit, delete, read, write data in the firestore, can a hacker decode the app and enter the database seeing passwords and deleting accounts?

Comment: No, as long as you have proper security rules setup your data should be good.

Comment: And for my case, what rules would be the best?

Comment: That can be answered if you share some screenshots of your Firestore database and explain what can a user access. e.g. a user can access their own doc or only admin can write data to a part, etc....

Comment: I think this is what you need

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Dharmaraj: note that OP uses Python, and the Python SDK is an Admin SDK so not affected by security rules. Using Pyrebase (or the REST API that is built on top of) would allow to secure access through rules for Python code.